# What is an open source Home Theater OS for a Media PC?

Tags: home-theater, operating-systems

I currently have a spare computer which I want to convert into a Media PC. It should store all my movies, music, etc.

**Config:** *Pentium 4 3ghz - 1 GB RAM - 2 TB hard disk space, I have a JBL sound system which I would plug this up to.*

Any open source Home Theater OS available ? I don't want to spend on another licensed software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will only work well if you add a video card with hdmi that will do hardware acceleration. The P4 will really struggle with HD Video by itself.  If you're not worried about that, you could take a look at [MythTV](http://www.mythtv.org/).

Comment: I can buy a video card that's no problem, its not too costly

Answer (score 1):

Open Source Media Server: [MediaPortal](http://www.team-mediaportal.com/download.html)

Comment: You still need windows for this, although the software is open source and free. It's not the solution to this problem

Answer (score 1):

OpenELEC (http://www.openelec.tv) runs XBMC on a custom version of Linux, or use XBMCbuntu (http://xbmc.org/download/). Both of these use the excellent XBMC as the media player.